# print Alphabet pattern side by side

Tags: python, nested-loops, nested-lists

I have been trying to write a program, that prints the initials of my name in block letters side by side, but when I execute the code it prints the second letter below

```
name = "Weke Moyosore"
initials = "W M"


# code to print  W
for row in range(6):
    for col in range(7):
         if (
             (row == 5 and col == 1)
              or (row == 4 and col == 2)
              or col == 0
              or col == 5
              or (row == 4 and col == 3)
              or (row == 5 and col == 4)
              ):
            print("W", end="")

         else:
            print(end=" ")
    print()
    print("\r")

# Code to print M
for row in range(6):
    for col in range(7):
        if (
           (row == 1 and col == 1)
        or (row == 2 and col == 2)
        or col == 0
        or col == 5
        or (row == 1 and col == 4)
        or (row == 2 and col == 3)
            ):
          print("M", end="")

        else:
            print(end=" ")
            print()
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: make an example of your input and expected output.

Comment: I believe your very last `print()` is just indented too far. Unindent it until it's the last instruction in the outer for loop (unindent twice) and you'll get the M correct. (Of course it'll be below the W, but that is significantly more refactoring to get both letters side by side.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# code to print  W M
for row in range(6):
    for col in range(17):
         if (
             (row == 5 and col == 1)
              or (row == 4 and col == 2)
              or col == 0
              or col == 5
              or (row == 4 and col == 3)
              or (row == 5 and col == 4)
              ):
            print("W", end="")
         elif (
           (row == 1 and col == 11)
            or (row == 2 and col == 12)
            or col == 10
            or col == 15
            or (row == 1 and col == 14)
            or (row == 2 and col == 13)
            ):
          print("M", end="")
         else:
            print(end=" ")
    print()
```

Henry Ecker's comment about the indentation of the last print was correct and you need to use a higher figure for column to get the output side by side.

```
W    W    M    M 
W    W    MM  MM 
W    W    M MM M 
W    W    M    M 
W WW W    M    M 
WW  WW    M    M
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to construct the letters "W" and "M" row by row, and then print each row of "W" followed by the corresponding row of "M". This can be done for example as follows:

```
w_list = []
for row in range(6):
    s = ""
    for col in range(7):
        if ((row == 5 and col == 1) 
            or (row == 4 and col == 2) 
            or col == 0
            or col == 5 
            or (row == 4 and col == 3)
            or (row == 5 and col == 4)):
            s += "W"
        else:
            s += " "
    w_list.append(s)


m_list = []
for row in range(6):
    s = ""
    for col in range(7):
        if ((row == 1 and col == 1) 
            or (row == 2 and col == 2) 
            or col == 0
            or col == 5 
            or (row == 1 and col == 4)
            or (row == 2 and col == 3)):
            s += "M"
        else:
            s += " "
    m_list.append(s)

for w, m in zip(w_list, m_list):
    print(w, m)
```

It gives:

```
W    W  M    M 
W    W  MM  MM 
W    W  M MM M 
W    W  M    M 
W WW W  M    M 
WW  WW  M    M
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the second letter is below is because the way you're printing it out goes line by line.

So the way you'd want things to print is line by line:

```
W    W  M    M
```

Followed by:

```
W    W  M    M  
W    W  MM  MM
```

Followed by:

```
W    W  M    M  
W    W  MM  MM  
W    W  M MM M
```

You get the idea. I have written some code with comments for explanation:

```py
# Printing W M in Block letters

letterCount = 2 # Number of letters
colCount = (letterCount * 8) # Number of columns (7 col per letter + 1 col space)


for row in range(6):
    for col in range(colCount):
        
        # variable that always printed, space my default
        letter = " "
            
        #col/8 determines letter number. If result<1, it is the first letter, a.k.a W
        if (col/8<1):
            
            # Checking rows and cols for W, if true letter var will be changed to W
            if(
                (row == 5 and col == 1)
                or (row == 4 and col == 2)
                or col == 0
                or col == 5
                or (row == 4 and col == 3)
                or (row == 5 and col == 4)
               ):
                letter = "W"
                
        #col/8 result determins this is second letter
        if (1<= col/8 <2):

            # Check rows and cols for M, change letter var if needed
            if(
                (row == 1 and col%8 == 1)
                or (row == 2 and col%8 == 2)
                or col%8 == 0
                or col%8 == 5
                or (row == 1 and col%8 == 4)
                or (row == 2 and col%8 == 3)
               ):
                letter = "M"
        
        # print letter
        print(letter, end="")
    
    # new line after each row
    print()
```

result:

```
W    W  M    M  
W    W  MM  MM  
W    W  M MM M  
W    W  M    M  
W WW W  M    M  
WW  WW  M    M
```